# Confusion related to kruskal wallis test

Tags: matlab, kruskal-wallis-test

I have some confusion related to Kruskal wallis test. I have an example lets say

```
X=[2 2 35 10 9 8 11 12];
Y=[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2];
```

Y is the group variable

Now when I ran the kruskalwallis test

```
p = kruskalwallis(X,Y,'off')
```

I got p values of around 0.4. I was assuming the Kruskal wallis test takes the median. So it should have been robust when I added an outlier with value 35 in the third position. Why isn't it robust to that. Is it because I have very few samples. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I get a p-value of 0.0046 or 0.0030 with ties. Are you sure you're doing this test correctly?

Comment: I got very different values with the outlier (chi-square = 0.38, df = 1, p = 0.54) and without (chi-square = 16.25, df = 1, p = 0.00005) running `kruskal.test` from the `stats` package in `R`; very similar with wilcox.test

Comment: What package? Is that matlab?

Comment: yeah I am using matlab

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov. Yeah I am sure. How come you got 0.0046 abd 0.0030. I am using matlab. Are u using matlab?

Comment: @user34790 No, I am using Stata to do this. When I use the two-sample Wilcoxon (Mann-Whitney) test, of which the KW is a multi-sample generalization, I get p-value of 0.0030.

Answer (score 6):

If Y is meant to be a grouping variable, the p-value in R is around 0.45

```
> kruskal.test(x~y)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by y 
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.5622, df = 1, p-value = 0.4534
```

But it makes no difference whether that 35 is set to 13 or 35 or 1300 - the p-value is exactly the same. It is clearly robust to outliers.

With continuity correction, the p-value is somewhat higher.

---

Edit:

Here's an illustration of just how the Kruskal-Wallis p-value responds as you move the third observation around - that is, this is an empirical influence curve for the p-value as `x[3]` is moved (takes the various values of delta).

[image: Kruskal-Wallis p-value as x[3] changes]

We see that the Kruskal-Wallis is highly insensitive to all but a small range of values for `x[3]` (it is constant to the left of $[1,2]$ and constant to the right of it). It's *really* insensitive.

The grey line is the p-value with x[3] omitted. As you see, no value for `x[3]` will allow the Kruskal-Wallis to attain that p-value, though making `x[3]=2` comes closest.

---

> I was assuming the Kruskal wallis test takes the median.

It's a rank-based ANOVA. It doesn't actually 'use' the median for anything.

The measure of location-shift that corresponds to the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (and hence to the Kruskal-Wallis) is the median of pairwise differences between the samples.

```
> median(outer(x[y==1],x[y==2],"-"))
[1] -7
```

Compare:

```
> wilcox.test(x~y,conf.int=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x by y 
W = 5, p-value = 0.5486
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -10   5 
sample estimates:
difference in location 
             -6.999992    #<-------------------------------
```

(I'm not sure why it doesn't have better accuracy there)

If you change the 35 to 13 or 1300, you get the same estimate of shift.

If you add a whole new observation - if your original data in the first group was just (2, 2), then adding an additional observation changes the p-value. (This would be the case even if the median was the estimate of location shift.)

Comment: I am still getting 0.4 in matlab. I have followed the syntax. Can anyone confirm in matlab?

Comment: It may just be using a different approximation. The *exact* p-value is 29/56 = 0.5179. (Note that there are only 56 possible arrangements of 8 objects into two groups of 3 and 5 objects respectively.)

Answer (score 1):

You have the [MATLAB syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kruskalwallis.html) wrong, I think, or else I am testing the wrong hypothesis. If you have 2 samples of 8 observation each, then MATLAB expects the data to be in columns, so try `p=kruskalwallis([X',Y'])`. This gives me a p-value of 0.0030, as in Stata.

Here's my MATLAB output for the first case:

```
>> X

X =

     2     2    35    10     9     8    11    12

>> Y

Y =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2

>> [p,table]=kruskalwallis([X',Y'])

p =

    0.0030


table = 

    'Source'     'SS'          'df'    'MS'          'Chi-sq'    'Prob>Chi-sq'
    'Columns'    [182.2500]    [ 1]    [182.2500]    [8.8185]    [     0.0030]
    'Error'      [127.7500]    [14]    [  9.1250]          []               []
    'Total'      [     310]    [15]            []          []               []
```

If you meant for Y to be group variable, you get:

```
>> p=kruskalwallis(X',Y')

p =

    0.4534


>> p=kruskalwallis(X,Y)

p =

    0.4534
```

---

**Update:**

I am also very curious about this test, so I bootstrapped the adjusted p-value from the KW test. The distribution is shown below, with the observed p-value denoted by the dashed line. There's a lot of mass near 0, but also some near the observed p-value and near 1. Not quite sure what to make of that.

[image]

Comment: I have tried with the columns as well. It is still the same

Comment: I am not sure what's going wrong then.

Comment: That was my question. If I use Y as a group variable why do I get p value of 0.45 when I add an outlier. It means the test is not working properly.

Comment: Your assertion that 'the test is not working properly' is mistaken. When you *add* an observation to a sample, you totally change the conditions; it doesn't matter where you add it, you'll change the p-value in some way, and with such tiny samples, it can change a lot. I showed you that when you *move* an observation instead, then *as long as it was already outside the range of rest of the combined sample*, the K-W doesn't respond to it at all as you move it further from the data. The K-W seems to be behaving just as it should.